# Putting Banner Behing Adsense

Tags: html, css, ads, adsense

I am setting up adsense for my website at the moment and am trying to set a background-image behind the ad so that if someone visits the page with ad-block there is a image politely asking them to turn it on if they would like to support the website. Currently, I have wrapped the adsense code in a div and set a background-image on it, however when I do that my adblock software is able to detect it and block the image behind it. Would anyone be able to tell me the correct to do this? Cheers

HTML -

```
<div class="ad-alert">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Listings Banner -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9407013200292589" data-ad-slot="7535806952"></ins>
    <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.ad-alert {
    width: 728px;
    height: 90px;
    background-image: url("../images/ad-alert-banner.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it myself. The trick was to set the div background color through the CSS and then set a background-image which has the text you want with a transparent background. Below is an example.

CSS -

```
.ad-alert {
    width: 728px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #cccccc;
    background-image: url("../images/randompeople.png");
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Now you need to accept your own answer, very meta I know.

Comment: You can only accept your own answer after two days.

Comment: Thank you for educating me! I haven't posted questions here, but have found many pre-asked questions answered :-)